# Received inbox message about election that is underway, but there is no active election on the site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications, election, global-inbox

Just saw this:

[image: inbox message about election that is underway]

In words:

> The Stack Overflow 2020 community moderator election is underway — nominations now being accepted.

However, when [clicking the message](https://stackoverflow.com/election), I was greeted with:

[image: elections page saying there no active elections now]

Or in words:

> There are no active community moderator elections at the moment. Below is a historical record of all elections to date:

Can this please be fixed so that I won't get wrong and misleading inbox messages?

Comment: There is an election underway. Perhaps you just clicked the link too fast before the page updated? I don't know if there is caching to that page. Does it still show that message for you now?

Comment: it showed up for a few minutes, went away, and now it's back. don't think cache works that way

Comment: Thanks @animuson looks like there is 15 minutes cache. You recommend to edit this into feature request asking to delay the notification, or delete it?

Comment: This question seems valid to me. Looking over on SO meta, the automatic Community user announcement of the election ended up being posted three times: [once](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399104/2020-community-moderator-election), [twice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399108/2020-community-moderator-election), and [thrice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399110/). I think they accidentally canceled the election and restarted it a couple times; you happened to click it during the between time. This also explains why it showed up multiple times, @user400654.

Comment: I'm... not contesting the validity of this question.

Comment: @Sonic thanks, didn't dig that deep. So in such case, the messages should be auto deleted, same way comment replies are deleted when the comments are deleted.

Comment: @user400654 Not saying that you are. That text was directed at people who were downvoting and close-voting this question.

Comment: @CesarM Sha & ani, I received no notification, though clicking your link earned me a bronze badge; so I was eligible for the notification. You might modify it to that; oddly broken and inconsistent.

Comment: @Rob looks like Cesar deleted his comment and posted answer instead, so he missed your ping.

Comment: @Rob can you open another bug report if that's the case? It's unrelated to this one.

Comment: @CesarM, my comment was a [reply to this comment by Shadow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350474/received-inbox-message-about-election-that-is-underway-but-there-is-no-active-e#comment1173324_350474), where he wondered if he should generalize *this* Bug Report; I think mine would be either deemed a duplicate of this or garner comments saying it was related. As long as you are aware that's good enough for me. --- IF the system used a list of pregenerated messages that were referenced by a *pointer then 'mass notifications' could be sent/deleted instantly, to follow opening/closing ..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was probably caused by the election ending early and [needing to be restarted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399118/11092634).

Shouldn't be a recurring bug as it was caused by a human mistake on ending the wrong election.